# Trying to find and bridge USART pins from the manual of an STM32 board

Tags: stm32, uart, pinout, board

I am trying to solve an issue regarding a firmware with [this](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f302r8.html) 64-bit Nucleo Board.
I have the hex file and can see the ready source code but when I upload the firmware I am not able to communicate through virtual port via PC USB port.

I was suspicious of the USART settings and I noticed the firmware I am trying to use is using USART3. And in the Nucleo's manual [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105823-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf) the following is mentioned:

[image]

If I am not mistaken I need to do the above wiring to be able to communicate with the PC. Because in my case the firmware is configured for USART3.

And in my case USART3 is set as following:

[image]

So in my case the USART3 pins are:

PB10: USART3_Tx

PB11: USART3_Rx

And below is the board's connectors and pins:

[image]

**My questions are:**

1-) If what I am trying to do is correct, in my case(with [this](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f302r8.html) board) I need to connect:

PB10 to CN9 pin RX

PB11 to CN9 pin TX

If correct, which are PB10 and PB11 pins on the board connectors?

2-) I have the board in my hand and I cannot see any pin numbers on CN7 neither in real nor in the manual. How is it found which pin is where?

**Edit:**

Seems like I found the pin out [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105823-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf):

[image]

So my question is reduced to: Is the following correct way?:

D6(PB10) to CN9 pin RX(D0)

D10(PB11) to CN9 pin TX(D1)

Comment: It didnt work. PA2 and PA3 seems disabled. Can that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> D6(PB10) to CN9 pin RX(D0)

Yes, alternatively you could connect CN10.25 to CN9.1 (RX, D0)

> D10(PB11) to CN9 pin TX(D1)

No, D10 is PB6, not PB11. You need to connect CN10.18 to get PB11. CN10.18 to CN9.2 (TX, D1) is what you want

Comment: Thank you I think the pinout is correct but still cannot communicate through USB

Answer (score 0):

The USART - USB bridge is provided by **U2**, which also provides ST-LINK debugging interface. By default, its TX & RX pins are connected to PA2 & PA3 of your uC, passing thru solder bridges SB13 & SB14. These pins are also provided on **CN3**.

Make these connections:

- **CN3:RX** -> **CN9:7** or **CN10:25** (PB10 TX)
- **CN3:TX** -> **CN10:18** (PB11 RX)

If you want to use PA2 & PA3 for other purposes, you need to remove jumpers from SB13 & SB14. Otherwise, they too get USART signals.